# What PHP framework appropriate for a social network?

Tags: php

I wanna build a social network with PHP. Two important things which i care is **speed** and security. So, what PHP framework should i use for my web and why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP framework for Social Networking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380519/php-framework-for-social-networking)

Answer (score 4):

I expect you'll get a lot of posts saying that X is the bees knees - just as if you'd asked what programming language should you use to write a web-based application.

The bset one is the one which you think is best documented and you understand.

There's no end of frameworks to choose from - but good programming usually stands out as being well-documented, supported.

If you want a short list to choose from, I'd suggest seagull, cakephp, horde, zend, prado, symfony.

Why?

Because it's hard to write a secure web-base application - and its up to you to make it secure. There is no magic sauce you can download or buy which will make your application secure or fast. All you can do is equip yourself with tools you know how to use properly and understand how to apply them.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a framework, but have you considered [elgg](http://elgg.org/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Great answer by symcbean! I would suggest Symfony, though it has a strong learning curve. http://www.symfony-project.org/

Or if you are intersted in Python checkout Django!

Answer (score 0):

I thank that the best way in your case  - use Laravel framework. It has excellent security support and active community that can help to develop your app more faster.

The great example of social network based on Laravel you can see here
https://github.com/lvntayn/laravel-social-network

Comment: best way to provide answers to include code or samples here in SO rather than providing links to external sites